# vue3 child component won't load with computed data as property

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, vuejs3

Here's the problem I'm having. I have a Leads page, that is my `Leads.vue` template. It loads my leads and then passes the leads data to other components via props.

The `LeadSources` component receives a computed method as it's property.
You can see that on the `Leads.vue` page, the `LeadSources` component calls the `getSourceData()` method for it's property data.

When I check the value of the props for `LeadSources.vue` in the `setup()` the value for `chartData` initially is an empty array. If the page hot-reloads then the `LeadSources` apexchart will populate with the `:series` data but otherwise I cannot get it to work.

Essentially it works like this.

`Leads.vue` passes `getSourceData()` to the `LeadsSources.vue` component which on the `setup()` sets it as the variable `series` and tries to load the `apexchart` with it.

It will not work if I refresh my page but if I save something in my IDE, the hot-reload will load the updated apexchart and the data appears. It seems like the prop values don't get set in the `setup()` function the first time around. How do I architecturally get around this? What's the proper way to set this up? I can't tell if the issue is on the `leads.vue` side of things or with the way that the `LeadSources.vue` component is being put together.

Any help would be appreciated, I've spent way too long trying to get this to work properly.

`Leads.vue`

```
<template>
  <!--begin::Leads-->
  <div class="row gy-5 g-xl-8 mb-8">
    <div class="col-xxl-12">
      <LeadTracker
        :lead-data="leadData"
        :key="componentKey"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row gy-5 g-xl-8 mb-8">
    <div class="col-xxl-12">
      <LeadSources
        chart-color="primary"
        chart-height="500"
        :chart-data="getSourceData"
        :chart-threshold="sourceThreshold"
        widget-classes="lead-sources"
      ></LeadSources>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end::Leads-->
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, defineAsyncComponent, onMounted } from "vue";
import { setCurrentPageTitle } from "@/core/helpers/breadcrumb";
import LeadSources from "@/components/leads/sources/LeadSources.vue";
import LeadTracker from "@/components/leads/tracker/LeadTracker.vue";
import LeadService from "@/core/services/LeadService";
import ApiService from "@/core/services/ApiService";
import {Lead} from "@/core/interfaces/lead";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "leads",
  components: {
    LeadTracker,
    LeadSources
  },
  data() {
    return {
      leadData: [] as Lead[],
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: async function() {
    this.leadData = await new LeadService().getLeads()
  },
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      setCurrentPageTitle("Lead Activity");
    });

    const sourceThreshold = 5;

    return {
      sourceThreshold,
      componentKey: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getSourceData() {
      interface SingleSource {
        source: string;
        value: number;
      }
      const sourceData: Array<SingleSource> = [];

      // Make array for source names
      const sourceTypes = [];
      this.leadData.filter(lead => {
        if (!sourceTypes.includes(lead.source)) sourceTypes.push(lead.source);
      });

      // Create objects for each form by name, push to leadSourceData
      sourceTypes.filter(type => {
        let totalSourceLeads = 1;
        this.leadData.filter(form => {
          if (form.source == type) totalSourceLeads++;
        });

        const leadSourceData = {
          source: type,
          value: totalSourceLeads
        };
        sourceData.push(leadSourceData);
      });

      // Sort by source popularity
      sourceData.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
      });

      return sourceData;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

`LeadSources.vue`

```
<template>
  <!--begin::Lead Sources Widget-->
  <div :class="widgetClasses" class="card card-footprint">
    <!--begin::Body-->
    <div
      class="card-body p-0 d-flex justify-content-between flex-column overflow-hidden"
    >
      <div class="d-lg-flex flex-stack flex-grow-1 px-9 py-6">
        <!--begin::Text-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-column text-start col-lg-10">
          <span class="card-title">Lead Sources</span>
          <span class="card-description">Where your leads are coming from.</span>

          <!--begin::Chart-->
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <apexchart
              class="mixed-widget-10-chart lead-sources-donut"
              :options="chartOptions"
              :series="series"
              type="donut"
              :height="chartHeight"
              :threshold="chartThreshold"
            ></apexchart>
          </div>
          <!--end::Chart-->
        </div>

        <!--begin::Unused Data-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-lg-column lg-col-2 justify-content-between unused-data">
          <div class="alt-sources flex-fill">
            <div><span class="alt-header">Other Sources:</span></div>
            <div v-for="item in otherSources" :key="item.source">
              <span>{{ item.source }}</span>
              <span>{{ item.value }}%</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="alt-sources flex-fill">
            <div><span class="alt-header">Sources Not Utilized:</span></div>
            <div v-for="item in unusedSources" :key="item.source">
              <span>{{ item.source }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end::Unused Data-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end::Lead Sources Widget-->
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LeadSource",
  props: {
    widgetClasses: String,
    chartColor: String,
    chartHeight: String,
    chartLabels: Array,
    chartData: Array,
    chartThreshold: Number
  },
  setup(props) {
    const sum = (data) => {
      let total = 0;
      data?.map(function(v) {
        total += v;
      });
      return total;
    }

    const chartData = ref(props.chartData).value;

    const threshold = ref(props.chartThreshold).value;

    const usedSourcesLabel: string[] = [];
    const usedSourcesData: number[] = [];
    const otherSources: any = [];
    const unusedSources: any = [];

    const splitData = (data, max) => {
      // set used, other sources < 5%, unused sources
      data.filter((item) => {
        if (item.value > max) {
          usedSourcesLabel.push(item.source);
          usedSourcesData.push(item.value);
        } else if (item.value < max && item.value != 0 && item.value !== null) {
          otherSources.push(item);
        } else if (item.value == 0 || item.value === null) {
          unusedSources.push(item);
        }
      });
    };

    splitData(chartData, threshold);

    const chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        width: 380,
        type: "donut"
      },
      colors: [
        "#1C6767",
        "#CD2E3B",
        "#154D5D",
        "#F1D67E",
        "#4F9E82",
        "#EF8669",
        "#393939",
        "#30AEB4"
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          startAngle: -90,
          endAngle: 270
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      fill: {
        type: "gradient",
        gradient: {
          type: "horizontal",
          shadeIntensity: 0.5,
          opacityFrom: 1,
          opacityTo: 1,
          stops: [0, 100],
        }
      },
      legend: {
        show: true,
        position: "left",
        fontSize: "16px",
        height: 220,
        onItemClick: {
          toggleDataSeries: false
        },
        onItemHover: {
          highlightDataSeries: false
        },
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
          return val + " - " + opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex];
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: undefined
      },
      tooltip: {
        style: {
          fontSize: "14px"
        },
        marker: {
          show: false
        },
        y: {
          formatter: function(val) {
            return val + "%";
          },
          title: {
            formatter: (seriesName) => seriesName,
          },
        }
      },
      labels: usedSourcesLabel,
      annotations: {
        position: "front",
        yaxis: [{
          label: {
            text: "text annotation"
          }
        }],
        xaxis: [{
          label: {
            text: "text xaxis annotation"
          }
        }],
      },
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          legend: {
            position: "bottom",
            horizontalAlign: "left"
          }
        }
      }]
    };
    const series = usedSourcesData;
    return {
      chartOptions,
      series,
      otherSources,
      unusedSources
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

**Edited**

I will attach the `LeadService.ts` class as well as the `ApiService.ts` class so you can see where the data is coming from

`LeadService.ts`

```
import ApiService from "@/core/services/ApiService";
import {Lead} from "@/core/interfaces/lead";

export default class LeadService {

  getLeads() {

    const accountInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accountInfo') || '{}');

    ApiService.setHeader();

    return ApiService.query("/leads", {params: {client_id : accountInfo.client_id}})
      .then(({ data }) => {
        let leadData: Lead[] = data['Items'];
        return leadData;
      })
      .catch(({ response }) => {
        return response;
      });

  }
}
```

`ApiService.ts`

```
import { App } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import JwtService from "@/core/services/JwtService";
import { AxiosResponse, AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import auth from "@/core/helpers/auth";

/**
 * @description service to call HTTP request via Axios
 */
class ApiService {
  /**
   * @description property to share vue instance
   */
  public static vueInstance: App;

  /**
   * @description initialize vue axios
   */
  public static init(app: App<Element>) {
    ApiService.vueInstance = app;
    ApiService.vueInstance.use(VueAxios, axios);
    ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://api.domain.com/";
  }

  /**
   * @description set the default HTTP request headers
   */
  public static setHeader(): void {
    ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.headers.common[
      "Authorization"
    ] = `Bearer ${auth.getSignInUserSession().getIdToken().jwtToken}`;
    ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.headers.common[
      "Content-Type"
    ] = "application/json application/vnd.api+json";
  } 

  /**
   * @description send the GET HTTP request
   * @param resource: string
   * @param params: AxiosRequestConfig
   * @returns Promise<AxiosResponse>
   */
  public static query(
    resource: string,
    params: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return ApiService.vueInstance.axios.get(resource, params).catch(error => {
      // @TODO log out and send home if response is 401 bad auth
      throw new Error(`[KT] ApiService ${error}`);
    });
  }
}

export default ApiService;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is caused when you're calling the data from the api.
This code:

```
beforeCreate: async function() {
    this.leadData = await new LeadService().getLeads()
},
```

I'd refactor to

```
async created () {
    const service = new LeadService()
    const value = await service.getLeads()
}
```

Also it would be nice to be able to see how you're fetching your data.
Sometimes this code: `const value = await axios.get('/api/getStuff').data` can be problematic because of paratheses issues. Which causes the same issue you described of, hot reloading working, but fresh not. I suspect the same sort of issue relies of the code executing like => `(await new LeadService()).getLeads()` Where you're probably awaiting the class, rather than the actual async code.

Comment: I just added the service files for you to see how the data is loaded

Comment: thank you for this, I ended up doing it in a one-liner like so, but you are correct, the await was on the class and not the method




async created () {
    this.leadData = await (new LeadService()).getLeads()
  }